# c# limit for linq Where

Tags: c#, linq

this is stupid question but I didnt found any answer. I have asp.net core mvc project and I do this:

```
var model = await _db.MyDbSet.ToListAsync();
int Os = 0;
string name = User.Identity.Name;
Os = model.Where(s => s.UserName.Contains(name)).First().Os;
```

My problem is that in my db I have 900 +- rows. When I try to read from last row it throws error. When I then edit data to be on row for example 899 it works fine. So for example I have three rows. When I try to find in first two rows it works fine but when I try to find in third row it throws me error. When I then move data from third row to second row it works fine. So basically I am unable to take data from any last row. Some Idea? Error that I am talking about:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at VPSAplikace_WEB.Controllers.HomeController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Index>b__1(ZamestnanciModel s) in E:\Všechny programy C#\VPS\VPSAplikace WEB\VPSAplikace WEB\Views\Home\HomeController.cs:line 38
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereListIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at VPSAplikace_WEB.Controllers.HomeController.Index(String SendTo) in E:\Všechny programy C#\VPS\VPSAplikace WEB\VPSAplikace WEB\Views\Home\HomeController.cs:line 38
```

I tried: 1. Hard coding info on 'third  row' and it found alright. :

```
Console.WriteLine(_db.MyDbSet.Where(s => s.UserName == "SomeDataOnThirdRow").First().Os); //Returns data on last row
```

I find it very strange and dont know how to solve it because when I hard code it It finds all right but when i use variable or something it doesn't work even tho 'input' is same.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `First()` throws an exception, when sequence is empty. Also, can `UserName` has a `null` value?

Comment: Error `System.NullReferenceException` has nothing to do with limit or order of the row, this error tells that returned result is `null`, which will happen only when collection doesn't have item with the name you search for. Check that variables you are searching by has correct values.

Comment: UserName Cannot be null. I have checked it and for some reason it is not in the sequence when I put it on the last spot. On the other hand when I put it for example in the middle of db it works just fine. Thats why its so strange

Comment: I would say that issue is not in order of items, but what value you are searching and does this value actually exists in database. You mentioned that with hardcoded value query works, but with variable is not - I would suggest to debug and check that variable has correct value.

Comment: I have done that and it showed right value

Comment: if any `s.UserName` is null, then a `s.UserName.Contains(...)` will throw a NullReferenceException. A comparison (`s.UserName=="Some..."`) will not throw (but never find this row, of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First some advices. Instead of using `Where()` followed by `First()` use `First(s => s.UserName.Contains(name))` or `FirstOrDefault(s => s.UserName.Contains(name))`. Diffrent between First and FirstOrDefault is that first one throws exception when no elements where found and second one return null.

Do it even better! Build your query first then execute it against database to avoid loading and filtering data in memory `await _db.SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.UserName.Contains(name))` [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=efcore-3.1].

Going back to question as Pavel Anikhouski and Fabio mentioned `System.NullReferenceException` has nothing to do with querying. In case when `Where()` has no match it returns empty IEnumerable which is not NULL! `First()` on empty collection will throw `InvalidOperationException` (ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netcore-3.1).

**Are you sure that  User.Identity.Name has value?**

Comment: First of all thanks for everything. Second of all I have solved it. My problem was that I declared model that repesented whole list and then I searched in that model. for some odd reason it was unable to find it in model but was able to find when I wrote it with _db. I hope you understand, my english is bad. Anyway you helped my so I will accept this answer! Thanks all!